# MongoDB how to group by all fields defined inside array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

My document structure is like this:

```
{
  "workType": "String",
  "functionalArea": [],
  "gender": Boolean,
  "contractType": String    
}
```

I have an array of fields that i want to group data by those fields:

```
groupByFields = [
  "gender", "workType", "functionalArea"
];
```

My current function working with single field not, array of fields to group data by.

```
queryFilter = {aggregationField: "workType"};
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {
    $match: match
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $ifNull: ["$" + queryFilter.aggregationField, "Unknown"] },
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

But if i use from array to group by all fields inside array, how i can do that?
My sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb81"),
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : ["Education", "Management"],
    "locations" : [ 
        "Germany", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "gender" : "male",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "Afghan"
    ],
    "workType" : "Part Time",
    "contractType" : "Permanent",
 },
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb21"),
    "minimumEducation" : "Master",
    "functionalArea" : ["IT", "Management"],
    "locations" : [ 
        "Germany", 
        "Itly", 
        "US"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "gender" : "male",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "Afghan"
    ],
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "contractType" : "Short Term",
}
```

My current query return bellow result for one field `workType`:

```
{
  _id: "Part Time",
  total: 1
},
{
  _id: "Full Time",
  total: 1 
}
```

But what i want to do is pass an array of fields that i want to group data by those, such as `["workType", "functionalArea", "contractType", "gender"]`, and query should return count of data for each field.

If i use bellow query it group data with and condition, but what i want to take is separate result for each group.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {
     $match: match
  },
  {
     $group: {
       _id: {workType : {$ifNull: ["$workType", "Unknown"]},functionalArea:{$ifNull: ["$functionalArea", "Unknown"]}},
       total: { $sum: 1 }
     }
   }
  ]);
```

and return this result:

```
{_id: {workType: "Part Time", functionalArea: "IT Software"}, total: 2}

{_id: {workType: "Full Time", functionalArea: "IT Software"}, total: 23}

{_id: {workType: "Part Time", functionalArea: "Education"}, total: 3}
```

What i want to return is:

```
{_id: [{workType: "Part Time", total: 5}, {functionalArea: "IT Software", total: 25}, {functionalArea: "Education", total: 3}}
```

Comment: Sorry but no idea what you are looking for here. Perhaps show some data and an expected result from that.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have update my question, and sample data, with desired result.

Comment: Your're aggregation pipeline in the question cannot possibly return the result you are claiming. Try again. You also might try reviewing your account history. My review of it shows a good number of questions all with acceptable answers and **none** of which you have actually accepted. So one wonders why we should help you at all when you don't appear to acknowledge the help you have already received.

Comment: But your previous answers not return the result i want, i have commented all reasons that your answer not worked for my conditions, and not return result i want, so how should i accept them? Or its a must for u that every one should accept each answer you post?

Comment: My previous answers? Not what I'm talking about. Perhaps you should engage in a conversation on those answers with the people who gave them if you expect something different. Your "whole account history" here is a "black mark" to say the least. Perhaps you should be a little less "gimmie" and an little more "co-operatative". Yes? Question here makes no sense and has false conclusions. Fix it if you expect a result.